# Mullvad VPN (openvpn) keeps disconnecting / reconnecting (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, vpn, openvpn

New user of Ubuntu 14.04 here. Thanks to the community for all the support with answering questions!
The Mullvad VPN client breaks and re-establishes the connection every few minutes! In one example below, the connection was lost and re-established 2 - 3 times in 4 minutes! Below is the log from the Terminal (there are no problems when running Mullvad from Windows 7).
Please help me fix it! Thank you in advance!

```
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:7505
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 WARNING: file 'ssl/58755950645.key' is group or others accessible
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]37.48.74.16:1300
Wed Mar  4 23:11:47 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]37.48.74.16:1300, sid=53d0a476 8925e11d
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 CRL: CRL ssl/crl.pem is from a different issuer than the issuer of certificate C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=Mullvad CA, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=Mullvad CA, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 CRL: CRL ssl/crl.pem is from a different issuer than the issuer of certificate C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=master.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=master.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 Validating certificate key usage
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 CRL CHECK OK: C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=nl13.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:50 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=nl13.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Mar  4 23:11:56 2015 [nl13.mullvad.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]37.48.74.16:1300
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 SENT CONTROL [nl13.mullvad.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,ifconfig-ipv6 fd47:5332:6120:72::1003/112 fd47:5332:6120:72::,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 10.114.0.1,route-ipv6 0000::/2,route-ipv6 4000::/2,route-ipv6 8000::/2,route-ipv6 C000::/2,route-gateway 10.114.0.1,topology subnet,ifconfig 10.114.0.5 255.255.0.0'
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=dc:85:de:57:9a:87
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 ROUTE6: default_gateway=UNDEF
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=1, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=1
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.114.0.5/16 broadcast 10.114.255.255
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 /sbin/ip -6 addr add fd47:5332:6120:72::1003/112 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:11:59 2015 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1558 10.114.0.5 255.255.0.0 init
dhcp-option DNS 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip route add 37.48.74.16/32 via 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 add_route_ipv6(::/2 -> fd47:5332:6120:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add ::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 add_route_ipv6(4000::/2 -> fd47:5332:6120:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add 4000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 add_route_ipv6(8000::/2 -> fd47:5332:6120:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add 8000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 add_route_ipv6(c000::/2 -> fd47:5332:6120:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add c000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:12:00 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:7505
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 WARNING: file 'ssl/58755950645.key' is group or others accessible
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]46.21.99.25:1300
Wed Mar  4 23:13:10 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]46.21.99.25:1300, sid=b25a19cf 09d6252c
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 CRL: CRL ssl/crl.pem is from a different issuer than the issuer of certificate C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=Mullvad CA, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=Mullvad CA, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 CRL: CRL ssl/crl.pem is from a different issuer than the issuer of certificate C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=master.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=master.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 Validating certificate key usage
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 CRL CHECK OK: C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=se1.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:13 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=NA, ST=None, L=None, O=Mullvad, CN=se1.mullvad.net, emailAddress=info@mullvad.net
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Mar  4 23:13:19 2015 [se1.mullvad.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]46.21.99.25:1300
Wed Mar  4 23:13:21 2015 SENT CONTROL [se1.mullvad.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,ifconfig-ipv6 fd45:bcfd:8d71:72::1000/112 fd45:bcfd:8d71:72::,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 10.114.0.1,route-ipv6 0000::/2,route-ipv6 4000::/2,route-ipv6 8000::/2,route-ipv6 C000::/2,route-gateway 10.114.0.1,topology subnet,ifconfig 10.114.0.2 255.255.0.0'
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=dc:85:de:57:9a:87
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 ROUTE6: default_gateway=UNDEF
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=1, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=1
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.114.0.2/16 broadcast 10.114.255.255
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 /sbin/ip -6 addr add fd45:bcfd:8d71:72::1000/112 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:22 2015 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1558 10.114.0.2 255.255.0.0 init
dhcp-option DNS 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip route add 46.21.99.25/32 via 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.114.0.1
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 add_route_ipv6(::/2 -> fd45:bcfd:8d71:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add ::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 add_route_ipv6(4000::/2 -> fd45:bcfd:8d71:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add 4000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 add_route_ipv6(8000::/2 -> fd45:bcfd:8d71:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add 8000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 add_route_ipv6(c000::/2 -> fd45:bcfd:8d71:72:: metric -1) dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 /sbin/ip -6 route add c000::/2 dev tun0
Wed Mar  4 23:13:23 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: I don't see anything really in those logs suggesting it's something we can fix, and I've heard mullvad's OpenVPN isn't the most stable - have you actually checked with mullvad to see if their systems are operating as they should?

Comment: Based on the log entry at 23:13:10 the OpenVPN (modifed by Mullvad) process was restarted. You should check /var/lib/syslog for further information, maybe you can find a clue why that happened.

Comment: @Thomas W., thank you for your comment. I've sent an email to mullvad, waiting for reply. Are OpenVPN's from different VPN providers different? Could my connection be stable if I sign up for another provider (or if OpnVPN doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04, it would not work with any provider)?

Comment: @HontváriLevente, thank you for your comment. Could you please let me know what am I looking for in syslog? I am not a tech person and new to linux. Should I check it with the text editor?

Comment: Yes, you can use any text editor, or the command "less /var/log/syslog" in terminal. I cannot tell you what should you look for, but for example one obvious thing is sign of out of memory. I am using the OpenVPN package from the Ubuntu repository, and it is 100% stable, including on 14.04.

Comment: @HontváriLevente There is a data leak in OpenVPN in that it sometimes leaks DNS - I think that's already on their radar.  And there are ways to crash OpenVPN if you aren't careful (never consider software 100% stable)

Comment: @HontváriLevente, thanks for suggestion. I tried in terminal:
gedit /var/lib/syslog
This opens an empty file (even a second after mullvad disconnects).
I navigated to directory /var/lib and typed ls, cannot see any syslog file there.

Comment: Mullvad recommended to change protocol from "any" tpc, and change timeout from "35" to "60". This has not helped, still started to re-connect after a few mins.

Comment: /var/log/syslog

Comment: @HontváriLevente, using less /var/log/syslog, I noticed there there was only line that repeated both times during the last two drops and re-connections was:
Mar  9 22:54:32 user1-comp NetworkManager[787]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Please help me understand it and solve the problem.
No new responses from mullvad tech guys yet.

Comment: That seems the be the consequence of the restart, not the cause. Sorry, I have no more idea. You may want to try to install the OpenVPN package from the Ubuntu repository and configure it according to the instructions on the Mullvad website.

Comment: @HontváriLevente, thank you for your attention and comments.

Comment: The question is still live, someone plz help me with the problem.